# Multiple websites in IIS 7 Intranet

Tags: iis-7

I would like to set up multiple websites in an Intranet environment using IIS 7.
My goal is to to be able to access the websites like this

http://machinename/site1
http://machinename/site2 where machinename is the intranet server in which IIS is installed.

i created 2 websites in IIS manager using, Sites/Add Website and the pointed the Physical path to appropriate locations and then set the ports to 8084 and 8086.

But i am not able to access the sites.

http://machinename:8084/Site1
http://machinename:8086/Site2

would be great if someone can point me to the right direction.

Please note: i am able to access the site if try to access the sites with just http://machinename:8084 or 
http://machinename:8086

But i would like to have the Sitename in my url.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/Site1 and /Site2 are not separate websites. You only have one website. Those are directories under the root website.

Comment: Thanks.So how do i access these sites ?

Comment: Assuming you want to keep using the port numbers, you will need to create a folder under your websites called /Site1 and /Site2. If you want to use the http://name/SiteX format, you need to create a new site on port 80 and create two folders under it.

Comment: When you say folders do you mean Virtual directories ?

Comment: They could be virtual directories, but they could also be simple file system folders.

Comment: Since i wanted to use the port number, i created a new web site WebSite1 and then under that i created a new Virtual directory called Site1 and pointed to my physical path. Is that what you meant ?